# Better way to declare uninitialized variables

Tags: initialization, rust

Some libc functions, e.g. [`sigemptyset(set: *mut sigset_t)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/x86_64-apple-darwin/libc/fn.sigemptyset.html) take a pointer to a variable, treat it as uninitialized and initialize it.

I end up with this code:

```
let mut newmask = std::mem::uninitialized();
libc::sigemptyset(&mut newmask);
```

This is ok, but when I have many of those variables I end up with something like this:

```
let mut newmask = std::mem::uninitialized();
let mut oldmask = std::mem::uninitialized();
let mut pendmask = std::mem::uninitialized();
```

I could condense it:

```
use std::mem::unitialized as uninit;
let (mut newmask, mut oldmask, mut pendmask) = (uninit(), uninit(), uninit());
```

Is there a nicer way to write this code? For educational purposes I explicitly want to use libc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luckily, tuples are normal types, too. So how about:

```
let (mut newmask, mut oldmask, mut pendmask) = std::mem::uninitialized();
```

However, it won't get much nicer than this. Your best bet is to combine all your variables into a bigger type (like a tuple or a struct) and un-initialize that.

But it's fine that unsafe things are verbose and annoying to write. Uninitialized variables are really quite dangerous, especially when dealing with `Drop` types. I am sure you are already aware, but I still want to make sure everyone reads [the documentation of `uninitialized()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html) to understand all possible pitfalls.

Comment: I was aware that `uninitialized` was dangerous. I'm just using them to let FFI functions write to them. What was new that the let statement actually does a tuple and you can specify this as `uninitialized` and then the tuple is "disassembled" into three variables. Spooky! :)

Comment: Wow, that's the best documentation for a dangerous function I've ever read.  Thanks for the pointer!  (No pun intended)