# How to leave a fixed size array uninitalized?

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm writing bindings to an external C library and there's a function which gets a mutable `char` pointer to a buffer and fills it with some null-terminated log information. This information is always less than 512 bytes so I can safely write something like this:

```
let mut log: [c_char; 512];
myfunc(log.as_mut_ptr());
```

It doesn't work:

```
error[E0381]: use of possibly uninitialized variable: `log`
  --> src/a.rs:63:60
   |
63 |             myfunc(log.as_mut_ptr());
   |                               ^^^ use of possibly uninitialized `log`
```

I could do like this:

```
let log: [c_char; 512] = [0; 512];
```

I don't need to fill the buffer, it will be filled on the next line, so it's just a waste of time (not a lot, consider it as a challenge rather that a real performance boost).

Is it possible to say "hey compiler, this time it's okay to have uninitialized variable!" somehow?

Comment: Relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650879/2731452

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [`mem::uninitialized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html):

```
let mut log: [c_char; 512];
log = ::std::mem::uninitialized();
```

That will prevent the compiler from complaining, but you  should think carefully if you really need it. Use it only if you know exactly what you're doing (as I do).

Comment: Since `mem::uninitialized` is `unsafe`, you also have to wrap it in an `unsafe` block, which isn't necessary with `= [0; 512]`. (I figure you already know this, but it would be good to add to the answer for future readers.)

Comment: *but you should think carefully if you really need it* — you should also *benchmark* and *profile*, as it may not even make a difference to start with.

Comment: @trentcl, sure, this piece of code is a part of relatively huge uninitialized block already :)

Comment: @Shepmaster, You are right! This is a first thing one should do when going to optimizing something. And as I mentioned in the question I just wonder if leaving something uninitialized is possible.